# Is there any way to geth less CPU Usage, by a powershell Script like mine

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerSehll Script, which reads a ini file and creats a new one with the Syntax my data needs, in an infinite Loop. It looks like this:

```
for(;;) {
    $fileToCheck = "C:\test\test.ini"
    if (Test-Path $fileToCheck -PathType leaf)
    {
     $ini = Get-Content -Path C:\test\test.ini
        $out = "[Event]`nTop = DISPLAY`n[Display_00000]`nDisplay=" + $ini
        Add-Content -Path C:\test\exit.txt -Value $out
        Remove-Item C:\test\hallo.ini
    }
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it has to be a powershell Script. If it starts via the Task Scheduler by starting the Computer, I can see in the TaskManager that it takes more than 30% of the CPU Usage.

Is this normal for a script like this? And is there a way to reduce the amount of CPU Usage?

Comment: you may add a sleep - e.g. ```start-sleep -seconds 60```

Comment: Why would you need an infinite loop anyway?

Comment: PowerShell can be setup to be started on specific events (such as when a file is changed). But that is a huge topic I'm afraid.

Comment: sleep is not a solution for my problem beacuse the data can be dropped anytime to be chekced and had to be editet just in time

Comment: infinite loop because i wont the script working in the time where the test.ini is created, and for the rest of his life time

Answer (score 0):

You're reading and writing files in infinite loop without any delay, so the script performs as many of those operations as it can in a unit of time.

If you want to monitor a file for changes, you can play around with something like this:

```
Get-Content C:\TMP\in.txt -Wait | Add-Content c:\tmp\out.txt -Force -PassThru
```

`-Wait` causes `Get-Content` to keep the file open and output any new lines to the pipeline. It checks for changes every second, so cpu usage will be low. `-PassThru` outputs the lines to console, so it's useful for testing and you can remove it later.